# Xcode 5 'forgetting' header files..?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, xcode5

I've got a fairly large project and frequently Xcode will fail to automatically expand paths to include files, i.e.

```
#include "UHelp
```

does not properly expand with e.g. the `UHelper.h` header file (usually recently added to the project).

This happens mostly for C++ files (I believe).

Is there any workaround for this issue..? After a lot of clean project/clean build folder/rebuild all the issue eventually resolves itself, but rather non-deterministically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can normally solve this problem by closing out the project and deleting the derived data

Comment: Seems to help. Quite annoying as Xcode then has to rebuild all its indexes, rebuild stuff, etc. ... hope they fix it soon!

Answer (score 1):

Retrying completion by closing (esc) the active completion can work in some cases.

My suspicion: Xcode is updating the index and may be ready when you attempt completion later.

Like compilation, C++ indexing takes more time than C or Objective-C.

Comment: Hmm, good idea. Except I can't remember Xcode stating in the display-thingie it's indexing in these cases (it usually *does* that e.g. when opening new projects or stuff with no data in the derived data folder)

Comment: @ATV it won't generally display progress for live indexing updates (e.g. one modified source file).